# Adding haml-lint to travis

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, haml, travis-ci, haml-lint

Is there a way I can add `haml-lint` to travis? I tried this:

```
script:
  - bundle exec rubocop --config .rubocop.yml app/models/ app/controllers/ app/mailers/ spec/
  - RAILS_ENV=test xvfb-run bundle exec rspec
  - haml-lint
```

It didn't work. I got

```
haml-lint
/home/travis/build.sh: line 41: haml-lint: command not found
The command "haml-lint" exited with 127.
```

Do I have to use hook as their github [page](https://github.com/causes/haml-lint) says?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to add `haml-lint` to my gemfile.

So this would work:

```
group :test do
  gem 'haml-lint', require: false
end
```

I am not sure why but in `.travis.yml` I had to change:

```
script:
  - bundle exec rubocop --config .rubocop.yml app/models/ app/controllers/ app/mailers/ spec/
  - RAILS_ENV=test xvfb-run bundle exec rspec
  - haml-lint
```

to:

```
script:
  - bundle exec rubocop --config .rubocop.yml app/models/ app/controllers/ app/mailers/ spec/
  - RAILS_ENV=test xvfb-run bundle exec rspec
  - haml-lint app/views
```